# Static vector member of pointers to instances of its class

Tags: c++

I have a class `X` and I want to keep track of all instances of this class using a static vector member of pointers to `X` instances.

I think this is some of initialization issue even though I used `inline` which I thought would take care of declaration and definition (seen [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static))

> A static data member may be declared inline. An inline static data
> member can be defined in the class definition and may specify an
> initializer. It does not need an out-of-class definition.

**Question is:** How to append a static vector member of pointers to instances of `X`? (when initializing a new `X` object)

```
class X
{
public:

    inline static std::vector<X*> instances;

    X()
    {
        instances.emplace_back(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: All you need to do is (1) `instances.place_back(this)` in all constructors you implement   (2) Suppress all other implicitly generated constructors  (3)  Have the destructor remove itself from the vector.       If multiple threads may construct instances of your class, you'll need to consider synchronisation concerns.

Comment: @Peter What is `place_back()`? Is it a hybrid of `push_back()` and `emplace_back()`?

Comment: The code you have written seems to work fine. Can you explain what exactly is the problem?

Comment: unrelated: `emplace_*()` should be used if you still have to construct the item to be inserted, this is not the case.

Comment: Ok I found the problem: using `inline static` is a feature of c++17 and I wasn't compiling with the proper flag (`-std=c++17`)

Comment: @AdrianMole   `place_back()` was a typo.   I meant `push_back()`.